# Dynamically Injecting API Data into Lottie File (React)

Tags: reactjs, lottie

I have a lottie file I am trying to use in my react app, what I would like to do is dynamically inject API Data into the lottie file (two logos coming from an endpoint). I have been searching for ways to do this and I can not find a concrete way. Has anyone ever tried to take specific data from an API and dynamically inject it into a lottie file?

Tried react-lottie but it has breaking changes with anything over React 16. Also attempted lottie-react, but there is no prop to pass specific data to be injected into the lottie file.

to be more detailed, I have two circles in the animation that move around the screen, I would like to put two logos into those circles. In the assets array of my lottie file, here is the two objects I would like to manipulate, keep in mind the assets array has 40+ objects inside

```
        {
        "id": "comp_1",
        "nm": "Logo 1",
        "fr": 30,
        "layers": [
            {
                "ddd": 0,
                "ind": 1,
                "ty": 2,
                "nm": "Logo 1 Placeholder.png",
                "cl": "png",
                "hd": true,
                "refId": "image_0",
                "sr": 1,
                "ks": {
                    "o": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": 100,
                        "ix": 11
                    },
                    "r": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": 0,
                        "ix": 10
                    },
                    "p": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": [
                            400,
                            400,
                            0
                        ],
                        "ix": 2,
                        "l": 2
                    },
                    "a": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": [
                            400,
                            400,
                            0
                        ],
                        "ix": 1,
                        "l": 2
                    },
                    "s": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": [
                            85,
                            85,
                            100
                        ],
                        "ix": 6,
                        "l": 2
                    }
                },
                "ao": 0,
                "ip": 0,
                "op": 600,
                "st": 0,
                "bm": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "comp_2",
        "nm": "Logo 2",
        "fr": 30,
        "layers": [
            {
                "ddd": 0,
                "ind": 1,
                "ty": 2,
                "nm": "Logo 2 Placeholder.png",
                "cl": "png",
                "hd": true,
                "refId": "image_0",
                "sr": 1,
                "ks": {
                    "o": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": 100,
                        "ix": 11
                    },
                    "r": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": 0,
                        "ix": 10
                    },
                    "p": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": [
                            400,
                            400,
                            0
                        ],
                        "ix": 2,
                        "l": 2
                    },
                    "a": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": [
                            400,
                            400,
                            0
                        ],
                        "ix": 1,
                        "l": 2
                    },
                    "s": {
                        "a": 0,
                        "k": [
                            85,
                            85,
                            100
                        ],
                        "ix": 6,
                        "l": 2
                    }
                },
                "ao": 0,
                "ip": 0,
                "op": 600,
                "st": 0,
                "bm": 0
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. What kind of data do you want to pass to the Lottie animation? How does this data affect the Lottie animation? After all the Lottie file is just a JSON.

Comment: @Camilo added a little more context, I am a pretty seasoned react dev but have no experience with lottie file.

Comment: I think you will need to understand the Lottie file structure for being able to alter them. I do not know of any library for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: I use JavaScript to handle dynamic interactions with Lottie.**
**This will work only if the logos are `png` or `jpeg` or similar format**

Yes, you can unless the recieved API data as logo file must be either `base64` format or the `link` to the file location.

For more detail check the sample `JSON` file I created. What you can do dynamically is, after the page loaded or the Lottie file rendered as SVG, access the `assets` properties or array and then inner values,

- such as `p`, stands for picture (my guess) whose value can be dynamically changed and the value must be in the `base64` format.
- `u` stands for `url` and its value can be set to the file location as link

In case if your JSON file doesn't include the `assets` property or array, you can copy from here and paste it into your JSON file. After pasting make changes to the values of

- `w` stands for width and `h` stands for height to as per the logo dimensions.

Lastly if that doesn't work then finally you can update image data here`xlink:href=` in SVG when its rendered-on web browser. Check the SVG code below the JSON code

```
{
    "v": "5.12.1",
    "fr": 30,
    "ip": 0,
    "op": 60,
    "w": 1080,
    "h": 1080,
    "nm": "LottieDynamic",
    "ddd": 0,
    "assets": [
        {
            "id": "image_0",
            "w": 2032,
            "h": 2033,
            "u": "",
            "p": "data:image/png;base64, ......",
            "e": 1
        }
    ],
    "layers": [
        {
            "ddd": 0,
            "ind": 1,
            "ty": 2,
            "nm": "#insta.png",
            "ln": "insta",
            "cl": "png",
            "refId": "image_0",
            "sr": 1,
            "ks": {
                "o": {
                    "a": 0,
                    "k": 100,
                    "ix": 11
                },
                "r": {
                    "a": 1,
                    "k": [
                        {
                            "i": {
                                "x": [
                                    0.667
                                ],
                                "y": [
                                    1
                                ]
                            },
                            "o": {
                                "x": [
                                    0.333
                                ],
                                "y": [
                                    0
                                ]
                            },
                            "t": 0,
                            "s": [
                                0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "t": 60,
                            "s": [
                                360
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "ix": 10
                },
                "p": {
                    "a": 0,
                    "k": [
                        540,
                        540,
                        0
                    ],
                    "ix": 2,
                    "l": 2
                },
                "a": {
                    "a": 0,
                    "k": [
                        1016,
                        1016.5,
                        0
                    ],
                    "ix": 1,
                    "l": 2
                },
                "s": {
                    "a": 0,
                    "k": [
                        36,
                        36,
                        100
                    ],
                    "ix": 6,
                    "l": 2
                }
            },
            "ao": 0,
            "ip": 0,
            "op": 60,
            "st": 0,
            "bm": 0
        }
    ],
    "markers": [],
    "props": {}
}
```

SVG code

```
<svg width="1080" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 1080 1080" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="instaSVG">
        <rect id="insta 1" width="719.646" height="720" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
    </g>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
            <use xlink:href="#image0_702_3" transform="scale(0.000492126)" />
        </pattern>
        <image id="instImage" data-name="insta.png" width="2032" height="2033"
            xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,...." />
    </defs>
</svg>
```